# pyopengl 3d pose landmarks visualization

Tags: python, opengl, 3d

How to visualize a sequence of 83 pose landmarks in time in python 2.7+ and 3.4+?

`data.shape == (83, #frames, 3)`.

Matplotlib is not a choice for 3d graphics. I want something OpenGL friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found nice [c3d](https://github.com/EmbodiedCognition/py-c3d) python lib for reading and OpenGL-like displaying Motion Capture C3D files.